# Insert not working

Tags: visualforce, dml

I have this code which does not show any exception and although I see the insert happaning in the developers console the record is not actually being saved.
This method is called from a page like this:

```
<apex:page controller="PortfolioCatalogController">
    <c:ChatterComponent recordId="{!virtualCatalogId}"/>
</apex:page>
```

> ```
> public Id virtualCatalogId{
>   get{
>       if(virtualCatalogId == null){
>           try{
>               if([SELECT count() FROM Virtual_Product_Catalog__c] > 0)
>                   virtualCatalogId = [SELECT Id FROM Virtual_Product_Catalog__c LIMIT 1].Id;
>               else{
>                   Virtual_Product_Catalog__c virtualProductCatalog = new Virtual_Product_Catalog__c(Name='Protfolio Catalog');
>                   insert virtualProductCatalog;
>                   virtualCatalogId = virtualProductCatalog.Id;
>                   system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'virtualProductCatalog id: ' + virtualCatalogId);
>               }                   
>           }
>           catch(QueryException e){
>               system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, e);                 
>           } 
>           catch(DMLException e){
>               system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, e);         
>           } 
>       }
>       return virtualCatalogId;        
>   }
>   set;
> }
> ```

Why is this not working?

Comment: I think you should do a dml in action method through a button click or through the onload Action attribute .Not really sure why you want to do in getter!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with doug, DML inside of variable statement seems inconsistent....consider just making the Id get;set; and then writing another method to perform the query and assignment to your Id.  Then make the method the "action" element of the page.

Also, try taking the logging level off...just do a full debug of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's generally not good practice to have a getter with a side effect (inserting the record). The order in which these methods execute is not guaranteed so you could be seeing something you don't expect because of that. Check in the database with a query to ensure that the record really hasn't been inserted in case this is the issue.

What does the debug log say? Are you getting output from the debug statements inside the error handlers?

Comment: the debug log shows everything is fine and the query shows the record was not created